# RevTex's `citeautoscript` option isn't working with citation inside of a figure caption

Tags: floats, bibliographies, captions, citing, revtex

This code compiles fine:

```
\documentclass[prb]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption \cite{app}}
\end{figure}

\bibliography{Biblio}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}

\end{document}
```

I like to use RevTex's `autoscript` option, which moves the citation superscripts after any punctuation.  But if I change the first line above to

```
\documentclass[prb,citeautoscript]{revtex4-1}
```

I get the error message

```
Missing \endcsname inserted
<to be read again>
\color@endgroup
```

pointing to the line with the `\caption`, and my document doesn't compile.  Any idea what's causing this, or how I can get around it and use the `citeautoscript` functionality when I have a citation inside of a caption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a strange bug, but putting caption content in a separate line somehow works. No idea why though. MWE:

```
\documentclass[prb,citeautoscript]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{
Caption \cite{app}
}
\end{figure}



\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{app} Lorem ipsum
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is indeed a bizarre bug, but your workaround worked for me as well.  Thanks!